# "You beat me to it!" comments

Tags: discussion, comments, best-practices

Can we stop doing this? It doesn't add anything other than clutter.

Comment: I suppose if you really hate them that much you could always just flag them as noise...

Comment: I've occasionally wondered if I'm the only one who ever flags comments as noise. I've never seen a comment be deleted from such a flag.

Comment: @Ether isn't that self-fulfilling?  You'd never see a deleted comment, therefore....

Comment: I was going to ask this question...but...

Comment: @Tom: I was thinking that I would see the comment disappear if I was the final flagger. Perhaps not.

Comment: @Ether: I have seen comments disappear after I flag them, but only a handful of times over the past 6 months or so.

Comment: I don't care since it's out of a mood and "n new answers have been posted"

Answer (score 12):

No.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: (See Revision History)

Comment: Stop breaking stuff!

Comment: I wanted to add a clever comment, but Bill beat me to it!

Answer (score 4):

Flag it as noise, if you feel strongly enough about it.

If enough people feel the same way, they'll get deleted.