# Comments that say "you beat me by X seconds" and similar

Tags: support, comments, noise-reduction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You beat me to it!” comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48768/you-beat-me-to-it-comments)

Very often people leave comments such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587107/c-operator-overload-for/6587134#6587134):

> Beat by 7 seconds :) Haha. You win this round!

What's the policy on this? Are they discouraged? I think they should be as they don't add anything useful.

What should be done if you encounter one of such comments? Should they be flagged?

Comment: Just flag it...if enough people agree with you it'll get deleted; if not it won't

Comment: The worst are the ones who post that (and are "admitting defeat") but leave their identical (or inferior) answer anyway

Comment: Previous consensus seemed to be ["Flag them if you think they are noise"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48768/you-beat-me-to-it-comments). Don't really think we've changed on that stance.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48768/you-beat-me-to-it-comments beat you for like a year

Answer (score 12):

I honestly don't worry too much about these, but on reflection, "too chatty" fits this kind of comment very well.

Comment: you beat me by 400 seconds